# Admission/discharge joined into single episode of care

Tags: sql-server, date, join

My question is similar to the problem described here: [Check if date falls between previous row start date and end date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28843767/check-if-date-falls-between-previous-row-start-date-and-end-date/28872481#28872481)

However, in my data, there may be multiple events that overlap and I also want to return rows that don't. The data:

```
PatientID   Facility  Encounter #    FromDate      ToDate
-------------------------------------------------------------
    5          A         22         2017/02/14    2017/02/19
    5          B         55         2017/02/19    2017/04/15
    5          C         66         2017/04/15    2017/08/19
    7          A        198         2018/06/27    2018/08/13
    8          D        222         2019/07/18    2019/12/06
    8          A       2305         2019/12/06    2020/01/07
    8          C       2223         2020/03/31    2020/05/17
    9          C      12312         2018/01/12    2020/02/04
```

In the example above, the client 5 and 8 were admitted on their discharge dates (from previous encounters). Whenever the admission date is the same as discharge date of the preceding row (chronologically), I need to join the dates into one episode of care (e.g. for patient 5, it is encounters 22,55, and 66; for patient 8, it is encounter 222, 2305). I am also looking to output the cases where this is not the case (Patient ID 7 and 9 and encounter 2223 for patient 8)

Desired output:

```
PatientID   FromDate      ToDate
-----------------------------------
    5      2017/02/14    2017/08/19
    7      2018/06/27    2018/08/13
    8      2019/07/18    2020/01/07
    8      2020/03/31    2020/05/17
    9      2018/01/12    2020/02/04
```

I am using SQL Server 2016. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: In the future, provide SQL Fiddle with your tables and data already set up.   In addition, provide what you have attempted thus far.

Comment: Great points! My sincere apologies for not including either the SQL Fiddle or the code I have tried. Prior to posting, I have tried using CROSS APPLY akin to below, but got stuck on next steps.`SELECT Main.PatientID
      ,Main.FromDate
      ,Main.ToDate
      ,Main.Facility
      ,Main.[Encounter #]
      ,a.ToDate
      ,lag(a.ToDate) OVER (partition by Main.PatientID ORDER BY Main.FromDate)
FROM Encounter Main 
cross APPLY
(SELECT TOP 1 ToDate FROM Encounter NextAdm 
WHERE NextAdm.PatientID=Main.PatientID AND Main.ToDate=NextAdm.FromDate
ORDER BY ToDate DESC
) a
`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [recursive CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to join "previous" encounters with "subsequent" encounters.  The first step is to determine which records to begin with - in this case, we want to find records for a given patient whose `FromDate` have no matching `ToDate`.  We do this via left outer join and filtering for `null` values from the "previous" record:

```
select
  subs.PatientId
  , subs.FromDate
  , subs.ToDate
from
  Encounter subs
  left outer join Encounter prev
   on subs.PatientId = prev.PatientId
      and subs.FromDate = prev.ToDate
where
  -- we want encounters that aren't preceded
  -- by another encounter
  prev.PatientId is null
```

Next, we want to recursively join the results with the `Encounter` records for a given patient via previous `FromDate` equals subsequent `ToDate` so that we can extend the `ToDate` of our results.  We do this by inner joining the results (a CTE we'll call `CrossFacilityEncounter`) with the `Encounter` table on the previously mentioned criteria:

```
select
  prev.PatientId
  , prev.FromDate
  , subs.ToDate
from
  -- this CTE is the "previous" encounter
  CrossFacilityEncounter prev
  inner join Encounter subs
    on prev.PatientId = subs.PatientId
       and prev.ToDate = subs.FromDate
```

Putting it all together in a recursive CTE, you get:

```
with CrossFacilityEncounter
(
  PatientId
  , FromDate
  , ToDate
)
as
(
  -- start with first encounter in a sequence
  -- for a given patient
  select
    subs.PatientId
    , subs.FromDate
    , subs.ToDate
  from
    Encounter subs
    left outer join Encounter prev
     on subs.PatientId = prev.PatientId
        and subs.FromDate = prev.ToDate
  where
    -- we want encounters that aren't preceded
    -- by another encounter
    prev.PatientId is null
  UNION ALL
  select
    prev.PatientId
    , prev.FromDate
    , subs.ToDate
  from
    -- this CTE is the "previous" encounter
    CrossFacilityEncounter prev
    inner join Encounter subs
      on prev.PatientId = subs.PatientId
         and prev.ToDate = subs.FromDate
)
```

The result will provide us with the `PatientId`, each sequence's initial `FromDate`, and the `ToDate/FromDate` that is the end of one segment (encounter) of the sequence and the beginning of the next sequence (if applicable).  With this we can do many things, but you're merely interested in the start and end dates of a sequence, so simply return the maximum value of for `FromDate` for each `{PatientId, FromDate}` tuple:

```
select
  PatientId
  , FromDate
  , MAX(ToDate)
from
    CrossFacilityEncounter
group by
  PatientId
  , FromDate
order by
  PatientId
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/de2ff/2/0)

Comment: Thank you very much! I have just tried this adjusting the code for my own data, but for some reason the code has been running on a table of 50k records over an 90 mins (and still going). It is likely an issue on my end. Will be in touch.